# Ember Handlebars Generate Table

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to Ember/Handlebars and need to generate a navigation table with the form

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="headerRow"><td>Group 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="headerRow"><td>Group 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will allow me to have groups that can be dynamically expanded/contracted when the headerRow is clicked on.

Sample JSON data looks like

```
[{groupName: 'Group 1', item: 'item1'},{groupName: 'Group 1', item: 'item2'},{groupName: 'Group 2', item: 'item1'},{groupName: 'Group 2', item: 'item2'}]
```

I need to iterate through the data and create the tbody groups if the current groupName is different than the last group name. This is a trivial task in Javascript/jQuery to create the html as a string and add open and close tbody and header rows, but how do I do this in Handlebars. I cannot find a way to store the last group in a variable (so I can compare to the current group) while using the {{#each data as |item index|}} Handlebars formatting.

I have accomplished the task of generating the table via a JS string by using a helper function, but I need to attach component actions to the rows in the table. What is the correct way to do this in Ember? I'm using Ember CLI 2.9.1.

Comment: Here's a place to start: https://ember-twiddle.com/bb1e5a11ae918041c128ed44a1648406?openFiles=routes.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.menu-table.hbs  It seems wild that you are using a table for nav, and your JSON may need to be thought about differently - but the question of how to loop through array and seperate it into group is sound. I'd like to know too.

Comment: If you can change the JSON, here is another way to look at it: https://ember-twiddle.com/185cc50643ed07201c88a15a42b00324?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.components.menu-table.hbs%2Croutes.application.js

Comment: The navigation table is a really a sub content nav in the middle of the page, with respective data being loaded in an adjacent div. It is not the main site nav.

Comment: If it's not a table of data - it shouldn't be a table. https://www.quora.com/When-is-it-appropriate-to-use-tables-in-HTML

Comment: I went ahead and changed the JSON data format and that worked. I would still like to know how to do this without changing the JSON format as I wont always be in control of this.

Comment: You can use map() and filter() and functions like that, to pick through your data and create an array in a proper format to iterate over. jQuery's if else syntax may have felt trivial to you - but there is likely a better way in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `.reduce()` to restructure your data:

```
yourData.reduce((res,item) => {
  if(!res[item.groupName]) {
    res[item.groupName] = []
  }
  res[item.groupName].push(item.item);
  return res;
}, {});
```

Do this in a computed property.

This will produce a better structure:

```
{
  "Group 1": [
    "item1",
    "item2"
  ],
  "Group 2": [
    "item1",
    "item2"
  ]
}
```

Now its easy to produce the data you want:

```
{{#each-in data as |group items|}}
  <tbody>
    <tr class="headerRow"><td>{{group}}</td></tr>
    {{#each items as |item|}}
      <tr><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
{{/each-in}}
```